# Bind 9 configuration Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ubuntu-server, bind

I have an static IP and I 'm trying to configure a Bind9 service to translate the ip to a domain name. I followed a lot of tutos and guides, but something is wrong because I check a lot of times my configuration and I can't view any errors.

**My named.conf.local file**

```
//direct zone
zone "mydomain.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.mydomain";
};

//inverse zone
zone "192.in-addr.arpa" {

    type master;
    file "etc/bind/db.192";
};
```

**db.192 file**

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA mydomain.com. root.mydomain.com. (
              1     ; Serial
         604800     ; Refresh
          86400     ; Retry
        2419200     ; Expire
         604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  mydomain.com.
37.1.168    IN  PTR mydomain.com.
```

**My db.mydomain file**

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA mydomain.com. root.mydomain.com. (
              2     ; Serial
         604800     ; Refresh
          86400     ; Retry
        2419200     ; Expire
         604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  mydomain.com.
@   IN  A   192.168.1.37
@   IN  MX   0  mydomain.com.
www IN  A   192.168.1.37
```

So, I want to get access (using a translated name) outside the net, using the internet, I understand that I need that change the IP for my real static IP. But with this configuration I should to have access inside the net using a browser, really?
What I am doing bad?
How can I config it to get access outside the net?

Thanks in advance to everybody and sorry for to disturb.

Answer (score 0):

You could have 2 interrellated problems here - it's not clear from your post how you are using the nameserver.

If it's meant only for your LAN you need to set it up as a caching server and then ensure your PC's point to your nameserver.

If you want to be able to resolve your domains from the wider world you need to ensure 3 things are done, at least 2 of of which are missing at the moment.

1. You need to have at least  2 nameservers set up on different IPs and add the DNS records for both to your configs.
2. You need to set the nameservers (including their IP addresses) are  added to your registrar's settings for the domain.
3. You need to ensure your firewall/router is forwarding requests on UDP and tcp port 53 to your nameserver.

Note that because your nameserver is behind NAT even if all the above are done, if your computers are using other nameservers you won't get any response until you set the external IPs as the DNS lookup chain won't be able to complete.